EMA Crossover with Martingale Strategy for MetaTrader 5 (error)
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
input int EMA1_Period = 9;           // First EMA period
input int EMA2_Period = 20;          // Second EMA period
input double RiskPercent = 1.0;      // Risk percentage per trade
input double TakeProfitFactor = 1.5; // Take Profit as a factor of SL
input double StopLossPips = 50;      // Stop Loss in pips
input int MartingaleStep = 2;        // Martingale multiplier
input int MaxMartingaleSteps = 3;    // Maximum martingale steps

double Lots; // Trade lots

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   double ema1 = iMA(Symbol(), 0, EMA1_Period, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 0);
   double ema2 = iMA(Symbol(), 0, EMA2_Period, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 0);
   
   // Get the latest bid/ask prices
   double bid = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID), _Digits);
   double ask = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK), _Digits);
   
   // Check if there are open positions
   if (PositionsTotal() == 0)
   {
      // If EMA1 is above EMA2, it's a buy signal
      if (ema1 > ema2)
      {
         OpenTrade(ORDER_TYPE_BUY, ask);
      }
      // If EMA1 is below EMA2, it's a sell signal
      else if (ema1 < ema2)
      {
         OpenTrade(ORDER_TYPE_SELL, bid);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Implement martingale if there's a loss
      ManageMartingale();
   }
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Open trade function                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OpenTrade(int orderType, double price)
{
   double sl = 0, tp = 0;
   Lots = CalculateLots(); // Calculate the lot size based on risk percentage

   // Set stop loss and take profit
   if (orderType == ORDER_TYPE_BUY)
   {
      sl = NormalizeDouble(price - StopLossPips * _Point, _Digits);
      tp = NormalizeDouble(price + StopLossPips * TakeProfitFactor * _Point, _Digits);
   }
   else if (orderType == ORDER_TYPE_SELL)
   {
      sl = NormalizeDouble(price + StopLossPips * _Point, _Digits);
      tp = NormalizeDouble(price - StopLossPips * TakeProfitFactor * _Point, _Digits);
   }

   // Create the trade request structure
   MqlTradeRequest request;
   MqlTradeResult result;
   ZeroMemory(request);
   request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
   request.symbol = Symbol();
   request.volume = Lots;
   request.type = orderType;
   request.price = price;
   request.sl = sl;
   request.tp = tp;
   request.deviation = 10;
   request.magic = 123456;
   request.comment = "EMA Crossover EA";
   
   // Send the trade order
   OrderSend(request, result);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Manage martingale positions                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void ManageMartingale()
{
   for (int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (PositionSelect(Symbol())) // Select position by symbol
      {
         double posPrice = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);
         double currentPrice = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_BUY ? SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID) : SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK);
         double loss = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PROFIT);
         
         // If the position is in loss and within martingale steps
         if (loss < 0 && PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TICKET) <= MaxMartingaleSteps)
         {
            // Double the lot size for the next position
            Lots *= MartingaleStep;

            // Open the same position type but with a higher lot size
            if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
               OpenTrade(ORDER_TYPE_BUY, SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK));
            else
               OpenTrade(ORDER_TYPE_SELL, SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID));
         }
      }
   }
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate lot size based on risk percentage                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculateLots()
{
   double riskAmount = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) * (RiskPercent / 100); // Fixed AccountInfoDouble
   double stopLossValue = StopLossPips * SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
   return NormalizeDouble(riskAmount / stopLossValue, 2);
}


I have tried to code an ea based on ema 9 and ema 20 cross over with the help of chatgpt but it shows me this problem :
'iMA' - wrong parameters count  emadx.mq5   19  18
built-in: int iMA(const string,ENUM_TIMEFRAMES,int,int,ENUM_MA_METHOD,int)   emadx.mq5   19  18
'iMA' - wrong parameters count  emadx.mq5   20  18
built-in: int iMA(const string,ENUM_TIMEFRAMES,int,int,ENUM_MA_METHOD,int)   emadx.mq5   20  18
can someone please help me ?

It looks like you provided one parameter too much.
int  iMA(
   string               symbol,            // symbol name
   ENUM_TIMEFRAMES      period,            // period
   int                  ma_period,         // averaging period
   int                  ma_shift,          // horizontal shift
   ENUM_MA_METHOD       ma_method,         // smoothing type
   ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE   applied_price      // type of price or handle
   );

Here’s the official reference to the iMA() function in the MetaTrader 5 documentation, which explains the correct usage of the function with all required parameters:

MetaTrader 5 iMA() Function Reference

